# How does OpenMPI set process' rank

Tags: openmpi

I would like to "override" my processes' ranks, based on some algorithm, after they have been launched via `mpirun`.

I believed `mpirun` just sets the environment variables, like `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK` and `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_SIZE`, for the launched processes, and `MPI_Init` or `MPI_Comm_rank` then retrieve the values of these variable. However, re-setting these variables doesn't affect the rank.

So, how does `MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank)` actually figure out the rank?

Comment: If you are in control of the code, you can use `MPI_Comm_split` to create a custom communicator (identical to the world communicator) where the ranks will have permuted IDs.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMPI has two flags to help tune this:

```
--rank-by <foo>
```

Rank in round-robin fashion according to the specified object, defaults to slot. Supported options include slot, hwthread, core, L1cache, L2cache, L3cache, socket, numa, board, and node.

```
-rf, --rankfile <rankfile>
```

Provide a rankfile file.

Comment: "AFTER they have been launched via mpirun"